# users disappear from options menu when given uids under 1000

Tags: users

I wanted to stop particular user names appearing in the list of names at the log in screen. I remembered reading that this could be achieved by changing the user id of the account to something less than 1000 (I think I made it 990). So I did this. That worked fine, but now when I wanted to change it back, the name is not appearing in the list of user accounts in the `users and groups` menu under administration.

How do I modify the phantom account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the userid with `sudo usermod -u <new id> <username>`.

Btw: to hide users from log in screen: [How to hide users from the GDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-login-screen)

Answer (score 5):

*gdm* uses `UID_MIN` from `/etc/login.defs` to determine which user IDs are system users and which are regular users. If you adjust it to match your system's user range, *gdm* will show them at the login screen again.

For example, since users on my network have their uid start at 500, I changed `/etc/login.defs` so they could log in:

```
$ grep UID_MIN /etc/login.defs
UID_MIN          500
```

Answer (score 0):

If the users/groups are not showing up on the graphical administration there is something wrong with your /etc/passwd, /etc/group files.
Check the file contents, also from a terminal run:

```
sudo pwck
```

This will check for errors.

Answer (score -1):

The gdm login  lists ubuntu login user with a UID >=1000

So set this UID less than 1000 for the user which you dont want to show in the login screen.

Goto System -> Administration -> Users and Groups

Click the user name, go to advanced settings, then change the "User ID" to a different number less than 1000.

Comment: This isn't an answer to my question at all. I have already done what this answer suggeests. And the whole point is when I now go to System->Administratin->Users and Groups, the user _isn't there_