# How do I hide a user from the login list?

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide users from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-login-screen)

I'm setting Ubuntu 10.10 up on my father's desktop and have two user accounts, his and mine (for remote administration purposes).  How can I hide (but not delete) my user from the login list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great answer to this question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/): https://serverfault.com/questions/173044/ubuntu-login-page-where-to-specify-users-list-shown/173051#173051

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally users with UIDs lower than 1000 will not be listed as they are counted more as system accounts. You can still login, you just wont be listed.

```
sudo usermod -u 999 your-username
```

It's possible this may break gnome for this user but if you're remote only, it wont hurt. To fix this,

```
sudo chown -R your-username:your-username /home/your-username
```