# Auto-login not working

Tags: 11.04, login-screen

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 11.04 to login automatically, but the login screen options don't seem to allow this.

There is no option to select my username, as this screenshot shows:

[image: shot]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the username you'd expect to show up? (any 'weird' characters in it?) I would file a bug on this if I was you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/739323), do you have your home partition encrypted with encryptfs? If so, that might be the reason. Then either do not use autologin or do not have encrypted $HOME, those two cannot go together (on requires password for decrypting the home directory, the other wants to avoid entering passwords)

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks. I had enabled home folder encryption on install. The encryption is more important to me, so I can live with it.

Answer (score 1):

These settings are store inside /etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin={username}
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=user
TimedLoginDelay=10
```

You can edit this from commandline by doing `gksu gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf`. Change your name where it says {username}. See if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` with your favorite editor.

Add (or change) following line, to make it look like this:

```
[greeter]
Exclude=teamspeak, nobody (or any user you want)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, user accounts with ids below 1000 will not be listed in this box.  See [How do I hide a user from the login list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18318/how-do-i-hide-a-user-from-the-login-list) for more details.