# How do I clear the list of recent files in Unity Files and Folders Lens?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

How do I clear the list of recent files in Unity Files and Folders Lens ??