# Hidden files are shown in Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, zeitgeist, hidden-files

I have several hidden files in a folder that are private and need to remain private. 
I do not mind people seeing what I do on my system but after I open one of these files I can find them through dash and I can even open them.

Am I misunderstanding the usage of hidden files? 
Can I tell dash to exclude hidden files?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a known issue with the current implementation of Zeitgeist in Natty & Oneiric - the software that drives the Dash searching capability.

Zeitgeist Privacy has finally landed in 12.04 (Precise) - it has not been backported to Natty or Oneiric.

By default, privacy hides hidden files.  That's the good news.

---

However, if you have got your files in a hidden folder then those files are not hidden.

Thus to hide a hidden folder and its contents you need to explicitly hide that folder.

To do this, launch *Privacy* from the *System Settings*

[image]

Click the button shown and this will show the directory window

[image]

Navigate to the folder below where the hidden folder is located.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reveal the location bar and enter the name of your hidden folder.

[image]

Once you select the OK button, no further activity will be recorded in your hidden folder.

To remove current activity, use the linked question for further help.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

Comment: If this has been a known bug since Maverick, nobody has yet fixed it (as of Oneiric).  Files that have been deleted are showing up in Dash: these include both text files and binary files of all sorts, and thumbnails of deleted pictures even show up.  Are the Zeitgeist people just not interested in fixing this major security problem?

Comment: @Kelley - Precise brings good news... - see my edit

Comment: @Kelley It isn't about zeitgeist, but Unity. I can add a feature in Privacy settings to allow you to delete the history for the blacklist which you have set. Sadly that cannot be included in precise because the freeze is in effect. After I have added that feature, i will edit the answer.

Comment: can i get the same thing done in gnome version as the privacy option is absent in it