# Hidden files showed in the dash

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, files, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden files are shown in Dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38743/hidden-files-are-shown-in-dash)

Hidden files (With (.) before the name) are showed in the dash. 
Is there any way to fix it? The Ubuntu version is 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot.

Comment: I'll update the linked question & answer with the latest info

Answer (score -1):

I think your keyboard layout is not fix all keys and select perfect layout.

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: what is perfect layout?

Comment: This is very difficult to read.