# How can I clear the recent files from the movie player menu in 12.04?

Tags: totem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete totem’s history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40119/how-do-i-delete-totems-history)
>   [How do I delete the entire history (Recently Used Items) in the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86544/how-do-i-delete-the-entire-history-recently-used-items-in-the-dash)

In 12.04 Live-USB, I use Movie Player to watch movie or music video. All of the movie/music-video titles that I have seen using the Movie Player appears on the menu (under the Movie tab).

How to clear this list and how to prevent Movie Player from showing this list anymore? I already try the "Delete History" from the "Privacy" option in "System Settings" but it doesn't work.