# How to delete list of played movies in Movie Player

Tags: video, video-player, history

Movie Player lists names of last few movies played.

How to delete that list ?

Going forward, I'll use VLC.  But I'd like to clear that viewed movie history list.

Comment: I think this is off-topic.

Comment: Can you manually delete the cache file? Such a file (if it exists) may be under ~/.cache/movie_player or some other similar address/path.

Comment: Movie Player?  Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Like this: http://askubuntu.com/a/41014/15811 (move player uses the same file).