# How can I prevent certain directories/files from appearing in Unity's dash?

Tags: 10.10, unity, search, zeitgeist, privacy

This question may sound similar to the following for which solutions are documented:

[How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

But my problem is that the Dash (in 10.10) not only lists recently touched files but *all* files on my mounted partitions (= obviously they are getting indexed automatically).

Is there any way to make Zeitgeist (the responsible application I guesss) exclude certain files/directory hierachies? Or is there any way to disable this kind of indexing completely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the answer in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29559) not address your needs?

Comment: This question (that I have also linked in my top post) deals with logging of recently used files. For this problem class the proposed solutions work. But I want to prevent certain directories from being indexed at all, they appear in the Dash as search results regardless of whether Zeitgeist has logged them as recently used or not. A rough workaround for this is to create ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/fts.index as an empty file (which is a directory usually). This disables indexing completely, but it would be better if there is a way to tell Zeitgeist to index just the "right things".

Comment: That blacklisting is blacklisting any furthur activity, but not previous ones. The results you are getting is from previous logged activities

Comment: It seems that my mistake was to completely delete the directory ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/ , I of course also deleted my blacklist this way! Now I tested to delete all files in the directory except the blacklist file, and it finally works the way I want. Thanks alot!

Comment: @ThePainter I am glad that you have finally found the solution that you most like. Please do post the comment as an answer so we can upvote you and close this question as answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally found an appropriate solution:
It seems that my mistake was to completely delete the directory ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/ , I of course also deleted my blacklist this way! Now I tested to delete all files in the directory except the blacklist file, and it finally works the way I want. Thanks alot!