# Exclude directory from Ubuntu search indexing?

Tags: 18.04, search, indexing

I have a directory in my Home that contains many small files and I would like to exclude it from indexing and search.

How can I do this?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/a/393248/307670

Comment: @Rinzwind I think it doesn't apply to 18.04, unfortunately.

Comment: @Graham Also seems to not apply to 18.04.

Comment: @Rinzwind As suggested in one of those answers I tried `touch .trackerignore` inside the directory I want to exclude. I'm not seeing it working yet (searching still returns results within this directory), but maybe I am supposed to wait a while for some caches to clear or something. Can you confirm if directories with a `.trackerignore` file are actually ignored in 18.04? Thanks!

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, tracker is not yet used by default. So this likely is not to be solved in Tracker, unless the OP has enabled it.

Comment: Hmmm, now I am confused. Is this contradicting what @Rinzwind just said?