# How to exclude a specific folder from search in Synapse?

Tags: unity, security, privacy, synapse

I added excluded folder to Security & Privacy settings and I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70854/how-to-remove-a-specific-folder-from-the-ubuntu-search) instructions but all of them seem to be working only when using Unity Dash search.

Inside System and Home Dir. I could find two files with configuration that belong to Synapse, file `synapse`:

```
?package(synapse):needs="X11"\
              section="Applications/File Management"\
              title="Synapse"\
              command="synapse" \
              hints="GNOME,Utility"
```

and `config.json`:

```
{
  "ui" : {
    "global" : {
      "ui-type" : "default",
      "show-indicator" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Can I somehow prevent it not to use my specific folder in Synapse search results or it's a different file/app that needs to be edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appeared to be a confusing explanation to my issue, in order to blacklist/exclude activity in desired folder I had to provide a complete path to every folder in subfolders section. Because I blacklisted a folder which has subfolders in it and the funny thing that adding this folder to excluded ones on Security & Privacy settings wasn't enough to block its subfolders in Synapse for some reason it let it through. I don't understand why it doesn't block its subfolders activity when the main (desired) folder is excluded/blacklisted? I guess it's a different question but anyways providing a complete path to each folder solved my issue.

Comment: where was that path "provided" exactly?

Comment: Well it was somewhere in the Settings, the answer is 4 years old, can't quite remember exactly.