# Hiding Files From Dash Search

Tags: unity-dash, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

I have images and videos that I want to have hidden from the Files and videos lens searches in my dash. (Nothing dirty, just ponies :P)

Anyway....Is there a way to have a file or even a folder not show up? Would hiding the files or folders do the trick, or is there more that I need to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04, there is 'Privacy', a software that comes pre-installed that lets you customize what will and what will not be stored by Zeitgeist that the dash uses to search for content.

So go ahead and search your system for Privacy, and look at its functions.
It is pretty straight forward from there. You just select the folders with the content that you don't want showing up.

[image]
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I just looked for that and it's missing. :( Both under System Settings and under Dash. I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and noticed that a few things were missing from my install...I'm guessing this is missing too. Could you do me a favor and see if you can tell me the application name for Privacy?

Comment: Whoever has the Privacy application: Can you open up `gnome-system-monitor` while you have Privacy opened to see the process name? I need to install it but I can't find the package name.

Comment: Using Gnome-system-monitor didn't help, but I discovered the package name using synaptic. "activity-log-manager-control-center"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'll go ahead and run this, and I'll accept your answer if it works :P

Comment: My version is 12.04 and updated to the latest. I don't know if this is a bug, and if it has been corrected in 12.10. Just selecting the "Don't record activity for following type of files" in privacy, didn't work globally. I had to add specific folders - then it worked.