# How to remove specific entries found in Dash

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

When I type in the Dash menu it looks for anything I have opened that resembles what I am typing. In this case I do not want to show some entries that appear when I type **screen**. For example I want to remove the 2 that appear in the list:

[image]

Comment: @Takkat - Correct, it is the same. Thank you. I could not find the other one when I looked for it.

Comment: Yeah - it is a miracle to me how it comes that sometimes I immediately find something whereas at other times I cant remember even though I even wrote an answer ;)

Comment: That is not the worst part. The worst is: You make the question, get a great answer and 6 months later you can´t find the question ^^.