# Removing/Preventing Dash from recording file when copied

Tags: unity-dash

Not sure if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything exactly the same.
I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Dash automatically saves a file as recently used even if all I did was ***move/copy*** it.
I wish to prevent this from happening but do not understand why it even records this data.

P.S. I wish to do this without removing all my recent files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

Comment: The exact settings window looks a bit different in newer releases, but its location and basic functionality is still the same.

Comment: I checked that question but they are talking about removing recently used files. I want to keep those, just want to remove the **copied** files that show up in my dash

Comment: Probably not easily doable, whenever you move/copy a file it gets "accessed" (you can check "properties" of the newly copied/moved file, the last access time should be when it was copied/moved). So it is automatically added to the "recent files" list.