# How can I disable recent documents in Unity?

Tags: unity, zeitgeist

How do I disable the tracking and display of recently opened files (and whatever else is remembered) in a default installation of Ubuntu? (This question originally concerned 11.10, but now that I'm on 12.04, that's the answer I've selected.)

(Note that this is not a duplicate of [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/29559/19501), since that question and its answers are concerned with temporary and specific filtering. I want to disable it completely for a single user account.)

---

Okay, to deflect the inevitable and expand on my motivation...

While trawling the usual forums and Google results for a solution, it (unsurprisingly) seems that the near-universal use cases for this request are either [browsing porn](https://askubuntu.com/q/28977/19501) or [Warhammer research](https://askubuntu.com/a/28981/19501). And the obvious solution to this is to create another user account to contain all evidence.

However, this is not why I'm asking, and I don't say that to get all high and mighty about it, it's because this answer won't help. (Even though I really *don't* have any interest in Warhammer, and I have no idea how that paint pot and brush ended up in my drawer, no that's not glue on my thumb, etc.)

My actual use case is that I use my personal laptop for presentations in different circles of my life. I have a user account set up with all the settings I like for presentations (shortcuts, small launcher, default associations, etc). But I don't want an accidental keystroke (or the find dialog) to display other recent presentations I've given, or the files I used in composing the presentation, or whatever. I also don't want to have to recreate this profile for every single presentation I might give. I just want a nice little isolated, memoryless, clean corner of my notebook for public display.

Comment: It's often helpful to say why you want things, since there can be better ways of accomplishing it, or things you'll loose that you weren't aware of, etc.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad - yes indeed, I was just editing for that purpose :)

Comment: You need to follow @jokerdino suggestion and use "All History" and click Delete. Now the history should not be shown in Unity

Comment: @ManishSinha - yes, I'll try that when 12.04 is released and I'm prepared to use it. Until then, unless there's an answer for 11.10, I can't accept it.

Comment: @detly This tool is available even for 11.10, will build it for 11.10 and add it to Zeitgeist PPA (within 24 hours)

Comment: @ManishSinha - before you go to the trouble, I already have `activity-log-manager` 0.8.0-0ubuntu1~ppa2 installed from the Zeitgeist PPA. Is there a newer version?

Comment: The latest version of the activity log manager (for Precise) is 0.9.4-0ubuntu1. So, when Manish backports it to 11.10, you can disable the recent documents.

Comment: @jokerdino Actually, I think the updates to the underlying libs might have fixed the problem. Give me a day to check, and if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @jokerdino Yes. `0.9.4` was uploaded less than 12 hours back. It fixes a lot of i18n and UI issues. Anyway I will backport `activity-log-manager` for `oneiric`

Comment: @detly 0.8.0 can do the same thing. It just looks different and the first tab is named different. Choose `All History` and clear it

Comment: @ManishSinha - clearing history was not the issue, stopping all logging was. `0.8.0` didn't do that (despite appearances), but your recent updates to the Zeitgeist PPA seem to have fixed whatever problem was causing that.

Comment: @ManishSinha - there's no 0.9.4 version in the Zeitgeist PPA — did you end up backporting it? Also, there's no "All History" button or option anywhere in 0.8.0.

Comment: @detly Hopefully will do it today.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` and choose `Privacy`.

Then, turn off the button next to *Record Activity*. Now, your recent documents will no longer be logged by Zeitgeist.

[image: System Settings Privacy Manager in Ubuntu 12.04]

Comment: I'll have to wait until I'm ready to use 12.04. Hopefully they'll have fixed whatever issues Activity Monitor currently has.

Comment: Your instructions for 11.10 should include using the PPA mentioned by @Manish Sinha — following these instructions for the `activity-log-manager` available in the official repos was the first thing I tried, and it never worked. It only seems to work now with the updated libraries.

Comment: @detly I can't quite tell which PPA you used that helped you solve the problem. Perhaps, you can edit the answer and add that part yourself?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't actually seem to work after all. Also, what version of `activity-log-manager` do you have installed in that first screenshot? Mine has no "Recent items" tab, nor a "Delete history" button; just a "History" tab and a calendar based deletion that doesn't really work.

Comment: @detly I guess it is version 0.9.

Comment: Hmm, I only have `0.8.0-1~oneiric1`.

Comment: @detly Are you on 12.04 yet?

Comment: Nope :/ It's on my to-do list, for next time I take a sick day.

Comment: @detly Alrightie. Was just curious.

Comment: Finally got to try it, and yes, it does work in 12.04 :)

Comment: @detly Thanks for the accept. Happy to help. :)

Comment: You might want to just remove the 11.10 info - it didn't work, but 12.04 is current and LTS anyway.

Comment: @detly Thanks. Removed 11.10. Hope that is coherent enough.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution in the ubuntuforums at comment #3, but don't know if it works. Give it a try:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860785

Comment: I've already tried the `recently-used.xbel` thing without success, but I'll try the Activity Monitor approach.

Comment: Hmm, disabling logging in the Activity Monitor doesn't seem to make any difference. (This is simply by clicking the big button at the bottom right of the dialog.)

Answer (score 1):

for whatever documents you don't wish to see under the recent documents tab; do the following :

1. Make sure you keep all such files in a folder.
2. After accessing it every time, just rename the folder.

just by renaming the folder you will see the magic working :)

Answer (score 1):

rename `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file (for example `recently-used.xbel--`) and create an empty folder and name it `recently-used.xbel` in same folder. That is all.

Comment: [Nope.](http://askubuntu.com/a/92743/19501)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable video recording at settings, privacy, files.
You can also tell Ubuntu which folders shouldn't be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

if you have upgraded to 12.10 already, do this:

go to: **System Setting/Privacy/Files**

then tick: **Video** and **Image**

check if it helps in case you still want your **txt** and **docs** activity to be available.

EDIT: Also, even better is to use the option **"Don't record activity in the following folders:"** what is the best customization I can see :), may be it is time to upgrade to 12.10  :D