# Hidden accounts

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide users from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-login-screen)

When you start up Ubuntu, it displays the usernames you can log on as as well as an "Other" option, where you are then prompted to type in the username. Is there a way to set up an account so that it doesn't show up on the list, but can be reached through the other option?

Comment: If i understand correctly, this question may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-login-screen