# Hide a particular account from user accounts

Tags: 14.04, users, system-settings

How to hide a particular administrator account from user accounts in system settings? I need it for security reasons. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible Duplicates? http://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-lightdm-login-screen, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen

Comment: @Mitch No, the OP states that he wants to hide the account in the _user accounts list_ in the _system settings_. The questions you link to are about hiding it in the GDM / LightDM login window.

Answer (score 1):

The accounts shown in the user accounts dialog are those with a UID in the range `UID_MIN` to `UID_MAX`. System accounts are those with uids in the range `SYS_UID_MIN` to `SYS_UID_MAX`. These constants are defined in `/etc/login.defs`.

If you don't want an account to show up in the dialog, create it as a system account:

```
adduser --system [...] username
```

If the user account already exists, you could reassign its uid to one in the system range:

```
usermod --uid 999 username
```

Note however, that hiding an account from the user accounts dialogue buys you no security whatsoever. The exact same information can be obtained using a simple `cat /etc/passwd`. Obscurity is not security.