# Why do MS-SQL and RStudio have users on my log-in screen?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, users, rstudio, mssql

I attempted to log in today and discovered that I had more users than I thought. It seems that both MS-SQL and RStudio users exist on my PC and are visible on my log-in screen. I've ran SQL on my laptop before, but only in a localhost setup that let me learn the language. Is there any good reason why I should have these users or any good reason why I shouldn't get rid of them?

Note that `id -u mssql` returns `997` and `id -u rstudio-server` returns `998`.

Comment: How did you do your discovery? Are you seeing entries for them on the log in screen?

Comment: @vanadium Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: Clarify your question to reflect that: use "edit".

Comment: @vanadium Already have.

Comment: I see, great. What are the uids of these users? I guess they will be larger than 1000. You can hide them from GDM login screen as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen

Comment: @vanadium Weirdly enough, `id` doesn't return them, but `id -u mssql` returns 997.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The users shown at the greeter need to be at minimum (and the maximum `UID_MAX`) what is set in `/etc/login.defs` at `UID_MIN`.

The range 1–499 (Red Hat, CentOS) or 1–999 (Debian, Ubuntu) are reserved for system users, including users allocated when installing a package containing a system service that requires a dedicated user.

So your mssql user having 997 is correct. That user should, in default Ubuntu, not be shown at the greeter when it is below 1000.

Please check what your minimum is set to. To get rid of user 997 one methoud should be changing that parameter to something above 997. If it is 1000 this is a bug and should be reported against the greeter you use.

Comment: My `login.defs` has `UID_MIN    1000` and `UID_MAX   60000` (yes, with that crazy indentation. Is this *certainly* a bug? Is there anywhere that I can check for silly little things like some boolean that I might've accidentally set somewhere?

Comment: @J.Mini yes it is a bug. It has happened before during beta that's why I believe it is a bug ;-)  You could alter the id of mssql to <500 to test if that works (500 is the real default, Debian is the system that started using 1000)

Comment: Don't suppose you happen to know if this is fixed in 22.04? I could always just twiddle my thumbs until that upgrade comes through.

Comment: I do not know that If you can I would advice using 22.04 over 20.04 but that is regardless of this issue ;-)

Comment: The issue has magically disappeared in 22.04.